# putting into consideration the argument between quotation marks

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to parse a command line string, at every white space putting into consideration the string has words between quotation marks. I want to store whatever is between 2 quotation marks as 1 index in a vector.

```
vector<string> words;
stringstream ss(userInput);
string currentWord;
vector<string> startWith;
stringstream sw(userInput);

while (getline(sw, currentWord, ' '))
    words.push_back(currentWord);

while (getline(ss, currentWord, '"'))
 startWith.push_back(currentWord); //if(currentWord.compare("")){ continue;}

for (int i = 0; i < startWith.size(); i++) 
    curr
    if(currentWord.compare("")){ continue;}   
     cout << " Index "<< i << ": " << startWith[i] << "\n";
```

Comment: [std::quoted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted)

Comment: @ZDF That's not available in C++11, starting with C++14.

Comment: @Murphy Correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you're trying to do. Here's a starting point ([run it](https://ideone.com/jXEwba)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::istream& get_word_or_quote( std::istream& is, std::string& s )
{
  char c;

  // skip ws and get the first character
  if ( !std::ws( is ) || !is.get( c ) )
    return is;

  // if it is a word
  if ( c != '"' )
  {
    is.putback( c );
    return is >> s;
  }

  // if it is a quote (no escape sequence)
  std::string q;
  while ( is.get( c ) && c != '"' )
    q += c;
  if ( c != '"' )
    throw "closing quote expected";

  //
  s = std::move( q );
  return is;
}

int main()
{
  std::istringstream is {"not-quoted \"quoted\" \"quoted with spaces\" \"no closing quote!" };

  try
  {
    std::string word;
    while ( get_word_or_quote( is, word ) )
      std::cout << word << std::endl;
  }
  catch ( const char* e )
  {
    std::cout << "ERROR: " << e;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The expected output is:

```
not-quoted
quoted
quoted with spaces
ERROR: closing quote expected
```